# Beats Studio Headphones with Skype?

Tags: bluetooth, skype

Ok so I cannot make my beats Studio 3 Headphones work with Skype, I'd like to use both the Headphones and Microsoft from the Beats with skype, I've seen plenty of solutions that say to just turn off the headset part of the headphones and while this does work it means I then can't use the microphone.

Has anyone managed to get this to work ok? I don't seem to have any problems using the headset in other software or on my phone.

I've tried both the classic version and Windows Store Version of Skype, both on Windows 10.

Comment: *I've seen plenty of solutions that say to just turn off the headset part of the headphones and while this does work it means I then can't use the microphone.* You're turning off the WRONG mode. For 2-way communications you need NOT the A2DP (HiFi Stereo, no mic) but HFP (hands-free profile, mono audio and mic) **and** make sure the correct output is selected in Skype settings.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Michael, I agree with what you are saying as a logical solution however this is the problem, If I enable Hands Free Profile instead of the Audio Only option I get no sound at all.... Not just through skype but through all applications.

Comment: Yes, it's logical *and* the starting point of the troubleshooting. Using a mode that can't possibly work is not. I suspect it's a settings issue, at Skype, the OS or both.

Comment: As far as I can tell I've tried all of the settings available to me, I think it's fair to assume this isn't a Skype issue as I get nothing through the headset regardless of which application I'm using, chrome, spotify & system sounds all don't play. 

I'm inclined to agree that this is a settings issue, but I can't see what the setting would be. I also haven't found any evidence of anyone actually getting beats to work with both the Microphone and the Headphones on a Windows Device.